# How to print the partial success message in console during Automation script run

Tags: selenium

All,

Thanks in advance.
How can i print the partial success message in my console.

Note : partial success message means , suppose After create a records, system displaying as "Customer created successfully" message in the page, From that message i want to print only the customer words.

The word customer is changing time to time, How can i proceed with this with the web driver.

Comment: Not clear what is your situation and what are you asking.

Comment: To properly assess the problem you need to provide the html, language, and code you are using **or** be much more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: What i am trying to say is : Generally when ever you will fill a online form it will display a message "Form created successfully", Here i want to print only the Form in my console not all the message.Hope now it clear for you.